# Using individual lines from grep outputs

Tags: scripting, grep

I'm trying to grab lines from grep and sorting them into another command, the command I'm using for grepping atm is as follows (hasn't yet been chopped enough for what I will be using it, but this gives better context):

```
iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep -oE '(ESSID:|Quality=|Encryption Key:).*'
```

Output looks like this (but will change depending on my computer's location):

```
Quality=64/70 Signal Level=-49dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"Hringdu_20558"
Quality=61/70 Signal Level=-48 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"SiminnEBE932"
Quality=30/70 Signal Level=-71 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"Siminn106C46
Quality=28/70 Signal Level=-83 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"SiminnECC63F"
```

I want to use these lines individually for executing another command

```
$ssid=$(zenity --list --text "Available Networks" --list --column "ESSID" --column "Secure" --column "Signal" "$ESSID" "$ENC" "$Signal");
```

These are the begginings of a quickie wireless network selection prompt. $ESSID/$ENC/$Signal would be based on the output from the earlier grep, so what I need to do essentially after working the grep output a bit more to look something like this in the end after chopping it with cut/awk/sed:

```
91%
on
Hringdu_20558
```

(note: I get the percentage by multiplying 64 by 10 then dividing by 7; 64*10/7)

Is to apply these lines recursively for every detected ESSID into the zenity command via scripting. And to add to problems; as you may notice the grep output is in reverse order from the zenity command, so this means "Hringdu_20558" would have to go in first, and "87%" would have to go in last.

In other words in this specific scenario I need to somehow grab the third line from the grep output, and append it to the other command, then work up the previous 2 lines, and repeat this going for the third line after the line I started until there are no more lines.

In essence the final zenity command should end up looking something like this based on the above outputs:

```
$ssid=$(zenity --list --text "Available Networks" --list --column "ESSID" --column "Secure" --column "Signal" "Hringdu_20558" "on" "91%" "SiminnEBE932" "on" "87%" "Siminn106C46" "on" "43%" "SiminnECC63F" "on" "40%");
```

How can I do this? Can it be done with just basic shell scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with something like this:

```
ssid=$(iwlist wlan0 scanning |
awk -F: '
BEGIN{ printf "zenity --list --text \"Available Networks\" --list --column ESSID --column Secure --column Signal "; }
/Quality/{ split($0,x,"="); Quality = int(x[2]*100/70+.5); }
/Encryption/{ Encryption = $2; }
/ESSID/{ ESSID = $2;
         printf "%s \"%s\" \"%s%%\" ", ESSID, Encryption, Quality
}' |
sh)
```

Doesn't really use grep, but it does what you want.

Comment: This seems to mostly work, I removed the grep part too. However, it fails to set the $ssid (so if I for example run this and then run echo $ssid, it will always print the first SSID no matter what I select in the menu) If I do $ssid=$(... (instead of ssid=$(... ) it seems to try to select the proper one, but it spits out a weird "not found" error while at it.

Comment: Maybe that weird behavior was because I was running it as root, hmm...

Comment: removing the ` \\\n` in the find printf might help. In your example `ESSID:"Siminn106C4` is missing a final `"`. I presume it is just a typo.

Comment: Yeah it was just a typo. I think i was running into problems with the ssid variable probably because I was running it from a sh file, Accounting properly for that I didn't have to change anything, your example was perfect (besides the grep) this definitely gets the job done, thank you.